# Issue with Android Developer Guide Start Another Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

So I've been learning Mobile App Development from the Android Development Website but there seems to be an issue:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#kotlin

the code to build an intent when clicking on the button does not seem to work:

```
const val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    fun sendMessage(view: View) {
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)
        val message = editText.text.toString()
        val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

I modified it a bit and it seems to work this way

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        btn.setOnClickListener{
            val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)
            val message = editText.text.toString()
            val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if I misunderstood something. If I did I'd like to be corrected. And if I didn't misunderstand and the code given doesn't work, how do I report the issue? I already unliked the page but the page didn't ask for more details.

Comment: because in code part 1,  you are not attaching the button listener and calling that function. in onCreate 
btn.setOnClickListener{
           sendMessage()
        }

Or you have to attach listener in XML.

Comment: I suspected that too so I added the listener in the second code while removing the sendMessage function altogether, but the android developer page doesn't tell me to add the button listener. It should be a reputable source that's why I'm so confused and trying to seek clarification. I'm confused because I don't know how view:View works as a parameter and I wonder if it could replace a button listener somehow and I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Read this below, they didn't show you the layout but explain it.
You have to attach onClick on button in XML. android:onClick="sendMessage".. that requires view attribute. 

"Return to the activity_main.xml file to call the method from the button:
Select the button in the Layout Editor.
In the Attributes window, locate the onClick property and select sendMessage [MainActivity] from its drop-down list."

Comment: That's exactly what I got wrong, thank you very much!

Comment: Best of luck :)